# Why do antibody tests target different antibodies?

Tags: immunology, antibody

I've noticed in various COVID-19 lateral flow assays, they seem to target different antibodies (S1, S2, NP). What are the benefits or downsides of choosing different antibodies? I know that some have a higher chance of cross-reactivity, but why wouldn't all tests just use the ones with the lowest cross-reactivity?

Comment: I think you're confused by polyclonal tests https://www.nature.com/articles/d41587-020-00010-2

Comment: I've used multiple assays. Some only respond positive to N Mab others respond positive to S1 Mab.