# What antibody targets are being tested for in the publicly offered UK antibody test?

Tags: immunology, lab-techniques, coronavirus, antibody

In late August 2021 the NHS (UK) offered people who test positive for COVID what is referred to in this [BBC report](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-58293249) as a *“new antibody test”*.

However, I have been unable to find out what exactly is new about this test. I was hoping to find what antibody targets are being tested for, including the virus strains used for them.

From what I understand there are many paths to immunity depending on the antibodies targeting one or more of the viral proteins.

[image]
<sub>image source: Murphy K, Weaver C. *Janeway’s Immunobiology*. 9th ed. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press; 2016. Table 10.27</sub>

Q: **What exact antibody targets are being tested for?**
(What is *"new"* about this?)

---

Possibly related questions:

- [How long after taking a vaccine shot (Oxford–AstraZeneca) could an individual test negative for antibody (IgM)?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/101016/how-long-after-taking-a-vaccine-shot-oxford-astrazeneca-could-an-individual-te)
- [Why do antibody tests target different antibodies?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92966/why-do-antibody-tests-target-different-antibodies)

Comment: I'm afraid this requires a bit of digging to find what you are actually referring to. The digging itself is not what people do here, so hopefully you'll find a lead to point us to. Otherwise you have to cross your fingers someone knows what exactly you are referring to. Good luck!

Comment: It could simply be semantics - the "new" part being that it is now offered, when it wasn't previously.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing I find as being "new" here, is that it is being offered for free. But still no clarity what exactly is being offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antibody tests have only been used on people involved in studies or surveys. This is the first time the tests are widely offered to the UK public for the purpose of collecting information about “*vaccine effectiveness and the immune response of the broader population*”.
This action is what they are referring to as “new” here, not the antibody test itself.

Comment: That is indeed unfortunate as *T-cells* cover a very important part of the overall immunity that is otherwise missed by the currently available tests.